# android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.mypackage.DetailsFragmentActivity; instances=2; limit=1

Tags: android

I am starting an fragment activity with many flags that should prevent multiple instances of the activity yet i still get the following error

> E/StrictMode(5920): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation:
>   class com.mypackage.DetailsFragmentActivity; instances=2; limit=1

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsFragmentActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
//              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
//              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
//              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
                activity.startActivity(intent);
```

I have strict mode enabled to detect activity leaks

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectActivityLeaks()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
```